# Issue linking SDL-2 statically in Visual Studio 2019 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, sdl-2, static-linking

I am trying to statically link SDL-2 in my Visual Studio 2019 project and I am getting the following error.

```
LNK4098 defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo@12              SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4        SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces@20        SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfacesDetailA@20  SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsA@16               SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA@28  SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __WinMain@16                                 LIBCMT.lib(exe_winmain.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common                     MSVCRT.lib(chandler4gs.obj)
```

The libs seem to be correctly linked and included. I have changed the `Code Generation` -> `Runtime Library` to `Multi-threaded Debug` and `Multi-threaded` for Debug and Release builds respectively.

The libs I have linked are `SDL2-staticd.lib` and `SDL2-static.lib` for Debug and release respectively as well as the `winmm.lib; imm32.lib; version.lib` libs in the `Additional Dependencies` section.

I also have the `C++ Language Standard` set to `ISO C++ 17 Standard (/std:c++17`.

I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4098?view=vs-2019) in reference to the LNK4098 error. For the Debug mode I added the library `libcmtd.lib` and Ignored `libcmt.lib; msvcrt.lib; msvcrtd.lib` which resolves the LNK4098 error.

However the errors I now get are as follows:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo@12              SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4        SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces@20        SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfacesDetailA@20  SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsA@16               SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA@28  SDL2-static.lib(hid.obj)

LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) libcmtd.lib(exe_main.obj)
```

With the last error being the new error.

Comment: [`SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdeviceinfo) lives in `Setupapi.lib`. IIRC `WinMain` should be provided by `SDL2main.lib` as a workaround for MSVC's wonky entry points. `__except_handler4_common` I'm not sure. I don't think you should be handling `libcmtd.lib` and `msvcrt.lib` manually.

Comment: Thank you - Addign Setupapi.lib removed the first LNK2001 errors and adding SDL2maind.lib and SDL2main.lib to Debug and Release removed the last error. The only thing I am getting now when running in Debug mode is a load of PDB warnings but other than that it works :) Is there a setting in CMake that I needed to check to get the PDB's?

Comment: @cookies it probably complains for missing pdb for each system's dll you use. MSVS can download them, and sometimes they help debugging to some extent, but otherwise not required.

Comment: @keltar ah alright, that makes a bit more sense now. I'll take a look, thank you!